# Stripping a value in Pandas to convert

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert an entire column in pandas form a string to a float.

In my column there is one figure stopping the conversion '66s' I would like to take the 's' off so I can convert.

```
dfWeather['HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF'].replace("s+", "")
dfWeather['HOURLYDewPointTempF'].replace("s+", "")
dfWeather = dfWeather.astype({"HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF": float, "HOURLYDewPointTempF": float})
```

When I run this code I get

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '66s
```

I would like to strip the 's' delete the 's' or even just replace the '66s' with a '66'

Comment: Use `dfWeather['HOURLYDRYBULBTEMPF'].replace("s+", "", regex=True)` instead

Comment: `replace` returns a copy.

Comment: What do you mean returns a copy?